# Does the developer of a Mac OS X app get the crash reports when the app crashes?

Tags: macos, crash-reports

If an app crashes while I'm using it in OS X I get a little (apparently) OS-driven dialog that lets me "report the crash to Apple". It sends along a stack trace and some other system information.

Does this crash information get shared with the app developer of the app in question at the time the crash occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iTunes Connect will let you get crash reports for your apps sold through the App Store. For all other apps, you'll need to implement your own crash reporting. (I mean, the Crash Reporter dialog shows up either way, but if you're not selling through iTunes Connect, there's no automatic way to get the information it collects.)

Comment: Not for Mac Apps on the MAS, though..?

Comment: D'oh - Nevermind, found it: *App Summary > Links > Crash Reports* :-)

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X Reference Library [Technical Note TN2123](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html) states:

> CrashReporter performs two useful
>   actions:
>
> - When a program crashes, CrashReporter will record a crash log
>     (typically into
>     ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/), and
>     inform the user by logging a message
>     to the system logging facility.
> - In addition, if the program that crashed is running as a logged in GUI
>     user, CrashReporter will present the
>     user with a dialog asking them whether
>     they want to submit a bug report to
>     Apple (see Figure 1). If the user
>     clicks the Report button,
>     CrashReporter displays another dialog
>     that shows the details of the report
>     (see Figure 2) and allows them to
>     comment it before submission.

And not much further along, states:

> In this technote I explain how to interpret crash logs that you have obtained from end users.

I believe this implies that the information is not automatically shared with the developer.  The developer needs to "obtain" the crash logs from the end users' ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like Flurry to get crash reports (and many other statistics) no matter where and how your application is deployed. Assuming you have internet connection of course.

Comment: Flurry does not support OS X SDK, so you actually can't.